# country drop down list and state/province text box are not working on one page checkout in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have being used magento 1.8.0.0.
I found that the one page checkout page drop down list are not working after i installed some plugins. But i checked that the plugins are not a cause for this issue. 
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Have you merged the js from admin panel? If yes then disable it from **admin > System > configuration > Developer > Javascript Settings tab > Set "Merge JavaScript Files" to "No".** 
Clear cache from "var/cache" folder.

Answer (score 0):

check that you have all js files on your

MAGETOAPP/desing/fontend/theme/template/checkout/onepage.phtml

script type="text/javascript" src="getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"

script type="text/javascript" src="getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"

script type="text/javascript">countryRegions = helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>

Comment: I have viewed that file and i have included all these files as you mentioned. But it's not working for me.